# Create a new branch with existing changes

Tags: git

I've cloned a master branch of a repository and made some changes. How do I create a branch with those changes? I don't want to push any of them to master.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you haven't committed yet:

```
$ git checkout -b <new_branch_name>   # create (and checkout) the new branch
$ git commit -a                       # commit to the new branch
```

If you have already committed (`master` contains your changes):

```
$ git branch <new_branch_name>     # create the new branch
$ git reset --hard HEAD^           # rewind master

$ git checkout <new_branch_name>   # switch to the new branch
```

Answer (score 1):

For future reference. Normally you branch off, before doing any changes. But for future reference

```
git stash save
git stash branch <branchname>
```